# How to use webpack to deploy an Express + React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, webpack

I have a project which for development uses webpack-dev-server. I would like to deploy the app using an express server that would serve its content via Pug templates, or just the static HTML page produced by HtmlWebpackPlugin when running production `webpack`. Current setup:

```
 ──┬   dist
 | └──┬   server
 | |  └──┬   views // moved by CopyWebpackPlugin
 | |  |  ├───   error.pug
 | |  |  └───   index.pug
 | |  ├───   index.js // bundled server
 | ├───   bundle.js   // bundled front-end
 | ├───   index.html  // produced by HtmlWebpackPlugin
 └─────   root.710...2.css
...

 ───┬   src
 |  └──┬   js
 |  |  ├───   app.jsx 
 |  └──┬   server
 |  |  └──┬   routes
 |  |  |  ├───   index.js  // route that might? serve index.pug
 |  |  |  ├───   routes.js // routes to other endpoints hit by front end code
 |  |  └──┬   views
 |  |  |  ├───   error.pug
 |  |  |  └───   index.pug // HtmlWebpackPlugin given this as template path
 |  |  ├───   app.js // express server
 |  └──┬   styles
 └─────└───   main.scss
```

Webpack bundles both my server and my front end components into `dist/server/index.js` and `dist/bundle.js`. The server provides a few routes that the front end XHR's to access some data. I'm struggling with how what the canonical way to deploy this code would be so that I can use the templated pages to display some variable information from the paths (eg, `error.pug` getting some data like `{code: 404}`) but also the hashes generated by HtmlWebpackPlugin that give urls like those produced by `filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js'`.

Should the express server not to attempt to serve the index based upon environment?

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
  })
}
```

If so, how should the pug template look like to consume the `[name].[hash].bundle.js`? Should the pug file be used only for the error page? Should it be a different Express server entirely that serves the index/error pages from a server that serves the API data consumed by the front end?

#### What is the canonical best practice to produce for production an express server to serve a bundled react app?

Answer (score 2):

Better is to have a dist this way

```
/dist
  /client
    root.710...2.css
    bundle.js
    index.html
  /server
    /views
      error.pug
      index.pug
    index.js
```

Then have your express server (or nginx) serve the client folder. 
`app.use(express.static('/path/to/your/dist/client'));`

Comment: And then during the build script use something like [copy webpack plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy `/src/server.js` into `/dist`?